# Arithmetic overflow error for select 2678400*1393 in SQL

Tags: sql-server

```
select 2678400 * 1393
```

When I run this query, I'm getting this error in SQL Server:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 23
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since this result overflows the capacity of `INT` - use `BIGINT` instead:

```
SELECT CAST(2678400 AS BIGINT) * 1393
```